# Should this question be open?

Tags: discussion, scope, off-topic, specific-question

Continuing my no doubt increasingly tiresome series of question in an effort to "get" this site. Should [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1697/is-rock-music-sinful-immoral?rq=1) be open?

It looks to me like a classic "Is X a sin?" type question. However, it does cite relevant examples which does help to scope the question and shows above average research effort against the yard stick of my experience here thusfar. It also seems to have been very well recieved.

So genuinely I ask should this question be open and if so/not why?

Comment: Plus, there's this last paragraph: "In answering the question, note that I'm not interested in debating whether or not rock music is actually immoral. I just want to know if / why groups of Christians believe it to be so." It is sufficiently scoped to remain open, and also the way it's set up makes it *not* an "Is X a sin?" question.

Comment: Also, I should note that you asking these sorts of questions time and time again to "get" this site is not tiresome because you actually receive and use the input you get, and you don't re-raise the same issues over and over again with little apparent improvement or understanding. So keep asking questions! :)

Comment: The title of that question should be edited to bring it in line with what the body of the question actually asks.

Comment: Haha, the title was actually made that way [by a site admin!](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/1697/revisions) Oops.

Comment: I'll second what El' said. I appreciate your desire, willingness and ability to grasp what's going on here and apply it to your posts.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a case of the question title and body not matching. The body was clearly asking for the basis for this belief, whereas the title was truthy. I edited the title so now it's all good.

Comment: Link bait, which we, as a community, have taken issue with in the past.